# Mixing two arrays by alternating elements two by two

Tags: c++, algorithm

What is an elegant algorithm to mix the elements two by two in two arrays (of potentially differing sizes) so that the items are drawn in an alternating fashion from each array, with the leftovers added to the end?

E.g.

```
Array 1:        0, 2, 4, 6

Array 2:        1, 3, 5, 7

Mixed array:    0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7
```

Don't worry about null checking or any other edge cases, I'll handle those.
Here is my solution but it does not work properly:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     arr[2 * i + 0] = A[i];
     arr[2 * i + 1] = A[i+1]; 

     arr[2 * i + 0] = B[i];
     arr[2 * i + 1] = B[i+1];
}
```

Comment: please show us your possibly unelegant algorithm, we'll try to guide you from there

Comment: I showed my algorithm above

Comment: N is the size of each array. I have no idea in solving this algorithm :(

Comment: Since you are using C++, why not use `std::vector` instead of plain arrays? That would save you some of the calculations; you could just `push_back` the elements as you build the result vector.

Comment: I don' understand you . Please be more concisely

Answer (score 1):

Some notes on the loop you have;

1. You use the same position in the result array `arr` to assign two values to it (one from `A` and one from `B`).
2. The calculation for the index is possibly more complex than it needs to be, consider using two indexers given the two ways you are indexing over the arrays.

I would propose you use a loop that has two indexers (`i` and `j`) and explicitly loop over the four elements of the result (i.e. two position for each input array). In each loop you increment the indexers appropriately (by 4 for the output array and by 2 for the input arrays).

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    constexpr int N = 4;
    int A[N] = {2, 4, 6, 8};
    int B[N] = {1, 3, 5, 7};
    int arr[N*2];
    for (auto i = 0, j=0; i < N*2; i+=4, j+=2) {
         arr[i + 0] = A[j];
         arr[i + 1] = A[j+1];
         arr[i + 2] = B[j];
         arr[i + 3] = B[j+1];
    }
    for (auto i =0; i < N*2; ++i) {
        cout << arr[i] << ",";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

*Note*: you mention you take care of corner cases, so the code here requires the input arrays to be of the same length and that the length is even.

Answer (score 1):

It is very fiddly to calculate the array indices explicitly, especially if your arrays can be of different and possibly odd lengths. It is easier if you keep three separate indices, one for each array:

```
int pairwise(int c[], const int a[], size_t alen, const int b[], size_t blen)
{
    size_t i = 0;       // index into a
    size_t j = 0;       // index into b
    size_t k = 0;       // index into c

    while (i < alen || j < blen) {
        if (i < alen) c[k++] = a[i++];
        if (i < alen) c[k++] = a[i++];
        if (j < blen) c[k++] = b[j++];
        if (j < blen) c[k++] = b[j++];
    }

    return k;
}
```

The returned value `k` will be equal to `alen` + `blen`, which is the implicit dimension of the result array `c`. Because the availability of a next item is checked for each array operation, this code works for arrays of different lengths and when the arrays have an odd number of elements.

You can use the code like this:

```
#define countof(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x))

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int b[] = {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6};

    int c[countof(a) + countof(b)];
    int i, n;

    n = pairwise(c, a, countof(a), b, countof(b));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i) printf(", ");
        printf("%d", c[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

(The example is in C, not C++, but your code doesn't use any of C++'s containers such as `vector`, so I've uses plain old ´int` arrays with explicit dimensions, which are the same in C and C++.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i += 2) {
     arr[2 * i + 0] = A[i];
     arr[2 * i + 1] = A[i+1]; 

     arr[2 * i + 2] = B[i];
     arr[2 * i + 3] = B[i+1];
}
```

Didn't consider any corner case, just fixing your concept. For example, check whether any array index out of bound occurs or not. You can run live [here](http://ideone.com/eyUhXs).

Answer (score 0):

it should like this.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i+=2) {
     arr[2 * i + 0] = A[i];
     arr[2 * i + 1] = A[i+1];    
     arr[2 * i + 2] = B[i];
     arr[2 * i + 3] = B[i+1];
}
```